# Action Script 3. How to add multiple children of 1 instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, instance, addchild

I'm creating flash game. I need to make player lives - heart images. If player have 5 lives should be added 5 hearts <3 <3 <3 <3 <3. I have image with instance name heart. How to add them correctly?

I've tried this:

```
var lives:Number = 4;
var currentHP = lives;
var heart:Heart = new Heart();
var hpArr:Array = new Array();
function hp() {         
    for (var i=0; i<lives; i++) {
        heart = new Heart();
        hpArr[i] = heart;
        hpArr.push(heart);
        heart.x += heart.width+20;
        addChild(heart);
    }
    trace("Array length" + hpArr.length);
}
```

This correctly return 5 `trace("Array length" + hpArr.length);`, so that means hearts successfully added to array. Problem is that only 1 heart is added. What can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` loop like this:

```
    for (var i=0; i<lives; i++) {
        heart = new Heart();
        hpArr.push(heart);
        heart.x = ( heart.width + 20 ) * i; // here is the trick!
        addChild(heart);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just found this issue by myself, thank you anyway! I needed to change `heart.x +=` to `heart.x =`

Comment: Could you help me to make lives auto update? I've tested It by button click. If I use `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hp);` It loop nonstop and adding many elements to array. Also tried to use this `hpArr.removeChild.hpArr[1];` in function where I need to lose heart, but I got error: `Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas just remove them from the array's end , something like `removeChild(hpArr.pop())`

Comment: I though to use lives++ if heart received and live -- when heart is lost, but nevermind this method will be good too. How to add heart to arrays end? addChild(hpArr.add())? Or no?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas you've already added it with a `hpArr.push(heart);` , now just `remove()` them on a button' click

Comment: I mean If player catch bonus heart I need to add new one to array and add bonus heart to stage

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas so put `for`'s content in a separate function and call it directly when you need it after

Comment: I have 1 problem, If I click button rules, later start button, again rules, again start, each time after start is clicked hearts is pushing to hpArr. I've used trace(hpArr.length), so after every time I click start button length increases.